# When to use JPARepositories?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

One of my tasks at work simply states "See if I can implement "JPARepositories" in an app that is built using Gradle. The whole reasoning is that they want to be able to use JPARepositories to extend PagingAndSortingRepositories.
Dumb question but since its already a gradle project I cant use the JPARepositories unless it was a spring boot app correct?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is just a build automation tool. You use it to manage dependencies and build the final executable jar/war.

You can use JPARepositories with Gradle/Maven or even with Ant build tools.
But JPARepositories are part of Spring Data JPA which requires you to at least use Spring if not Spring Boot because it uses Dependency Injection, Code generation etc heavily.

Basically you need to write a Spring application if you want to use Spring Data JPA and in turn JPARepositories.

Comment: Ok thanks, that’s exactly what I thought but needed confirmation